# How to handle the ecb menu CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, splistitem, ecb-menu

[image: I have hidden the ECB menu from the task/DocLib lists, and I am using jquery to truncate the title field into 50 char and remaining will be displayed in the jquery popup. Even though I have removed the ecb menu but I am getting the menu image will hovering the title value. How to resolve this?]

I have hidden the ECB menu from the task/DocLib lists, and I am using jquery to truncate the title field into 50 char and remaining will be displayed in the jquery popup. Even though I have removed the ecb menu but I am getting the menu image will hovering the title value. How to resolve this?
How should I handle this? (jquery/ ecb menu css / .js)

Comment: How did you hide it? It seems that "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" still displays in your list view. Go to view settings and in Columns display section check what column displays on your view. There should be "Title (linked to item)" or "Title", both will be displayed without ECB menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
.ms-vb-title .s4-ctx, .ms-itmhover
{
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
}
.ms-vb-title .s4-ctx img
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Worked for me.